# Use an External Javascript Library in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to install and use this library : https://wysihtml.com/ in my Vue.js project.

But I don't know how to import and use the scripts, or use the library at all.

```
<script src="bower_components/wysihtml/dist/wysihtml-toolbar.min.js"></script>
```

After some researches, I tried something like this : https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/22/vue-js-libraries-plugins/ but it didn't work for me too.

Do you have an idea ? What I am doing wrong ? Is it possible to use this library in my Vue.js project?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-wysihtml ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {},
  mounted() {
   var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor('editor', {
    toolbar: 'toolbar',
   });
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="toolbar">
    <a data-wysihtml5-command="bold">bold</a>
    <a data-wysihtml5-command="italic">italic</a>
    <a data-wysihtml5-command="formatBlock" data-wysihtml5-command-value="h1">H1</a>
    <a data-wysihtml5-command="formatBlock" data-wysihtml5-command-value="p">P</a>
  </div>
  <div id="editor" data-placeholder="Go on, start editing..."></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wysihtml/0.5.5/wysihtml.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wysihtml/0.5.5/wysihtml-toolbar.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have this error : "ReferenceError: wysihtml5 is not defined". Where should I define "wysihtml5" ? I can not see in your snippet

Comment: You must include script files:


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wysihtml/0.5.5/wysihtml.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wysihtml/0.5.5/wysihtml-toolbar.js"></script>

Comment: Yes! I did it, but I still have the error message... maybe Vue can't read the script file?